# Order of particles in a sentence

Tags: particles

I have a question about this sentence.

Q:  会社  ___  ____   ______  ______ 行っていますか.

A:  私は歩いて行っています.

I can use the particles 
で  は   へ  and 何.

According to the answer key, the correct order is:
会社何はでへで 行っていますか.

But I am stumped as to why they would go in this order?
I think my instinct is:
会社へ何では 行っていますか?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Where does the "correct" order come from? Textbook?

Comment: Yes, it's a textbook for the Japanese proficiency exam.

Comment: Just curious, could you show me what exactly your textbook says? It's so wildly wrong that I suspect there are some misunderstanding.

Answer (score 3):

The correct order according to your key is definitely strange Japanese (what is はでへで？？). Also your suggestion is a bit weird because ”何では" is not correct.

I would say:

> 会社へは何で行っていますか？

Personally I think saying ”どうやって" may be more natural instead of ”何で", though.

Comment: I agree with you.  どうやって sounds more correct.

Comment: @RetroGamer really? we frequently use XXへはなんで行ってますか/行きますか in daily conversation.

Comment: But doesn't ”なんで" also mean "because"? If so, I thought it would be more clearer to say "どうやって".

Comment: Maybe it is a regional difference or a more-casual register?  I must admit I haven't heard 何で used this way much either, but 何で as "by what means" seems to work here from a grammatical point of view, and it wouldn't surprise me at all if it was common usage in some contexts.